# array in curl or some other tool

Tags: curl

I drive trains. But i have a website that gets information about the train driving (like train numbers, meeting hours and so on) But the server i get my data from have been shutdown. The new server the developers have created is up and running but they are reluctant to give me the new information about the new host.

Could you setup a script (like curl or some other thing i dont know about) to see if a website is up and you are able to recieve information about that host AND do an array. Example

http://tXXXX.hostname.com:8083/API/somedata
(the XXXX starts from AAAA and then AAAB and then AAAC.... And so on and so on)

And when the host have some information the script stops or output the correct host to a file or something like that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [gnu-parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to run jobs concurrently, and only perform head requests with curl to speed things up, but there's still 456,976 to go through.

Here's what that would look like

```sh
printf '%s\n' {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z} | parallel --bar --halt now,success=1 -j4 'curl -LIfs -o /dev/null -m 10 http://t{}.hostname.com:8083/API/somedata && echo {}'
```

It will automatically stop when it gets a `200 OK` response from one of the curl requests. Each job is only allowed to run for 10 seconds, as specified by curl's `-m` option.

Comment: Thanks a bundle. I will look into gnu-parallel tomorrow. Yout been most helpful